# How can I create a simple JNI library that I can simply call methods from

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have an existing .c and .h file from a library. I would like to be able to call the functions contained within the c files from Java. I understand that this requires the JNI, and I have a pretty good understanding of how I will need to modify the .c and .h files in order to make them work with the JNI. What I don't fully understand how to do, or if it's even the purpose of the JNI, is to make a simple JNI library that I can then wrap into another java application. I want to create the interface; extend the C API into Java so I can use it there. The final result would be something like: someCmethodInSomeJNILibrary() located in some jnilib sort of file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: JNI creates the information the JVM needs to invoke the C code properly.  It is not easy to get right.  perhaps JNA would be easier to get working?

Comment: see this http://marakana.com/bookshelf/java_fundamentals_tutorial/_java_native_interface_jni.html

Comment: Google can give you some answers!

Comment: Since I had no idea that the JNA even existed until now, I'll look into that. Seems more like what I want. I'm not a major Java developer, but I like the super easy GUI creation it allows+cross platform nature.

Comment: There's also [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) that works similarly to JNA, but is more efficient and supports C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may wish to consider using JNA. JNA would allow you to interact without writing additional native code. This is particularly convenient if you already have a library and don't want to build another.

With JNI, the steps required include:

- Design a Java API of native methods for interacting with the C code.
- Use javah to generate C stubs for the Java native methods.
- Glue the C stubs to your C code.
- Generate a dynamic/shared library containing the native method functions and your original C code.
- Load that shared library in Java.

More detail can be found in ["Compiling, Loading, and Linking Native Methods"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp679) in the JNI documentation.